# How can I close this window after submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a JQuery pop-up window that renders a partial:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  editUserItem();
});

    function editUserItem(){
        var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=600,height=400");
        myWindow.document.write("<%= j render partial: 'edit_user_item_form', locals: {item: @user_item}%>"); 
    }

}
```

Here is the form in the partial:

```
<div class="edititem">
    <h4>Edit "<%= item.name %>"</h4>
    <%= form_for current_user.user_items.build, url: user_items_path, method: :patch,remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :id, value: item.id %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, value: item.name, class: "txt" %>
        <%= f.number_field :price, min: 0.00, :step => "0.01", value: item.price, class: "price"%>
        <%= f.select :category_id do %>
            <% current_user.categories.each do |category| %>
                <%= content_tag(:option, category.name, value: category.id) %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Update Item", class: 'submit-edit' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I'd like to close this window after submitting the form. I realize window.close() can only be used on windows that have been opened with window.open(), but this is the case. This is what I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  editUserItem();
  closeWindow();
});

function editUserItem(){
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=600,height=400");
    myWindow.document.write("<%= j render partial: 'edit_user_item_form', locals: {item: @user_item}%>"); 
    closeWindow();
}

function closeWindow(){
    $('.submit-edit').click(function() {
      myWindow.close();
    }); 
}
```

This does not work. I'm not sure if my JS script can "see" the submit button class I'm referencing in the form, and instead upon submission the pop-up simply renders the default 'update.html.erb'.

I also just found out about Modal windows...which as I understand it force the user to interact with it before going back to the original page. This would be more appropriate in this case, how might I implement this instead?

@guest271314 's script works after some modifications to fit into my rails app, but it still doesn't close the window...maybe I didn't stick it in the right place? I put it underneath my form_for:

```
<div class="edititem">
    <h4>Edit "<%= item.name %>"</h4>
    <%= form = form_for current_user.user_items.build, url: user_items_path, method: :patch,remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :id, value: item.id %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, value: item.name, class: "txt" %>
        <%= f.number_field :price, min: 0.00, :step => "0.01", value: item.price, class: "price"%>
        <%= f.select :category_id do %>
            <% current_user.categories.each do |category| %>
                <%= content_tag(:option, category.name, value: category.id) %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Update Item", class: 'submit-edit' %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  window.opener.console.log("form.html loaded");
  //const form = document.forms[0];
  form.onsubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("<%= user_items_path %>", {
        method: "PATCH",
        body: new FormData('<%= form %>')
      })
      .then(response => response.ok)
      .then(submitted => {
        if (submitted)
          window.close()
      })
      .catch(err => {
        window.opener.console.error(err)
      })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Put a `console.log('was called')` before `window.close` call in the `click` handler attached to `.submit-edit` to be sure that it's called when a click is done. Does `was called` get logged to the console when `.submit-edit` is clicked

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule no it doesn't get logged

Comment: Why is `const form = document.forms[0]` commented? Are `"<%= user_items_path %>"` and `'<%= form %>'` properly reflected at `<script>` at opened `document`? What occurs when the values are the full path to server and `new FormData(form)`?

Comment: because the form will not submit unless I insert my own form into your script. I updated my question to include the whole form + script

Comment: `const form = document.forms[0]` should still reference the `<form>` in the opened `document`. Without defining `form` the identifier will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default action of `<form>` submission, use `FormData` and `fetch()` to submit `<form>` elements. At chained `.then()` call `window.close()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
  window.opener.console.log("form.html loaded");
  const form = document.forms[0];
  form.onsubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("/path/to/server", {
        method: "POST",
        body: new FormData(form)
      })
      .then(response => response.ok)
      .then(submitted => {
        if (submitted)
          window.close()
      })
      .catch(err => {
        window.opener.console.error(err)
      })
  }
</script>   
</html>
```

Comment: I'll be honest, I have no idea what any of this means, and it seems purposefully complex for the sake of being complex. Surely there is a simpler solution.

I really just need to know where to stick window.close()....

Comment: @Jim The code is an example of the HTML `document`  including the `<form>` element to be submitted. Instead of submitting the `<form>`, when user clicks `<input type="submit">` `POST` a `FormData` object representation of the the `<form>` to server, at successful response from server close the opened `window`.The code achieves expect result described at OP.  Not sure what you mean by "complex" or "simpler". Those concepts were not considered when trying different approaches, only considered meeting requirement. You could alternatively use `postMessage` or `storage` event  to meet requirement.

Comment: OK, forgive my lack of JavaScript skills. 

So I've swapped out some things to fit this script into my application, but now on form submission I'm getting an 
'ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' error and my form is no longer being submitted. I had this error originally, and fixed it by adding 'authenticity_token: true' to my rails form. Perhaps I need to add a similar thing to my FormData object?

Comment: The example `<form>` at HTML at Question does not have a `name` attribute set. Include `name` attribute with a value which server expects at HTML, see https://plnkr.co/edit/zsAEes3b25LVtUv6P4dD?p=preview for demonstration of approach. Once the `<form>` is submitted a message is logged at `console` of `window.opener`, `window` should then close.

Comment: <%= form = form_for current_user.user_items.build, url: user_items_path, method: :patch,remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>

You mean like this? I did that, sorry i didn't post my updated form

Comment: Create an HTML `document` similar to the HTML `document` at Answer. If the code at comment creates the `<form>` dynamically then append that HTML to an HTML `document` with the `<script>` at Answer included.